# Can i add a static name inside the url for the root site inside my asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an asp.net mvc core web application, and currently when i access the root url it will be `https://localhost:44363/` which represents `https://localhost:44363/home/index`. but my question is if i can add a static name (our company name )inside the url for the root, so it will be `https://localhost:44363/OurCompnayName/home/index` ? can i modify the routing to achieve this or bu suing other techniques ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {

        //http://localhost:5000/shop            -> Products.Index()
        //http://localhost:5000/shop/newest     -> Products.Newest()
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "shop",
            pattern: "shop/{action=Index}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products" });

        //http://localhost:5000/company         -> Home.Index()
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "company",
            pattern: "company/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        //http://localhost:5000                 -> Home.Index()
        //You should allow default route just in case. Otherwise the base url returns 404
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)